# How to show Matrix in Sphinx Docs?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have a Matrix say 3 x 3, I want to display it in the Generated sphinx documentation of Python docs.

```
def Matrix_func():
    """
            [1  4  7 ]
    M   =   [2  5  8 ] 
            [3  6  9 ]
    """
```

Currently the above matrix is not printed as it is in the generated sphinx docs.

Comment: There are many formatting tools and methods available. Which ones have you tried, and what was the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can include the matrix in the function docstring:

```
def Matrix_func():
    """
    ::

             [1  4  7 ]
       M  =  [2  5  8 ] 
             [3  6  9 ]

    More text...

    """
```

Note the double colon (`::`), signifying a [literal block](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#literal-blocks).

Answer (score 11):

Or to use MathJax extension

In your sphinx `config.py` add the [`mathjax` extension](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/math.html#module-sphinx.ext.mathjax)

```
extensions = [
    # ... other extensions
    'sphinx.ext.mathjax',
]
```

Then a pretty array will render with:

```
def Matrix_func():
    r"""
    .. math::

        M = \begin{bmatrix}
                1 & 4 & 7 \\
                2 & 5 & 8 \\
                3 & 6 & 9
            \end{bmatrix}
    """
```

[image: rendered result]

this answer is 2.25 years late, but I hope it helps somebody ;)